# How to give value 0 to absent values

Tags: python, excel

I have a list of tuples, including the date, and the number of "beeps" on that date. However, if there were 0 beeps on a certain date, then that date is simply not present in the list. I need these dates to be present, with the number 0 for the beeps

I've tried solving this using excel and python, but I can't find a solution for it.

```
16/10/2017  7

18/10/2017  3

21/10/2017  7

23/10/2017  20

24/10/2017  7

25/10/2017  6
```

This is the start of what I have, and I need this to become:

```
16/10/2017  7

17/10/2017      0

18/10/2017  3

19/10/2017      0

20/10/2017      0

21/10/2017  7

22/10/2017      0

23/10/2017  20

24/10/2017  7

25/10/2017  6
```

Comment: Can you provide the code creating the tuples and/or the code processing them?

Comment: How is that data in python exactly? Is that tab separated values?

Comment: The data is in python as a list of lists. i.e. as a m*2 matrix, where m is about 1000. As you can probably tell, I'm a bit of a beginner, and so the code is such a mess, and I often have imported the data to fix things in excel, and then bring it back to python to do more complicated things. I suppose this is probably considered bad practise

Answer (score 1):

First save the first date with its value. Then iterate through the dates, saving the dates between the last saved date and the current date with a value of 0, then saving the current date with its value.

A psuedo-code solution would be:

```
last_saved_date, value = read_first_date()
save(last_saved_date, value)
while not_at_end_of_file():
    date, value = read_date()
    while last_saved_date + 1 < date:
        last_saved_date += 1
        save(last_saved_date, 0)
    save(date, value)
    last_saved_date = date
```

Comment: That looks super cool. Thank you! How do I iterate through a list of dates? Is there a package which handles this in python?

Comment: In  `read_date()`, you would have to have some way of parsing the date. I haven't delved to deep but https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/ looks like the kind of thing you want